# bootstrap class row col-sm-2 pushes label to next line

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a DIV class row like below

```
<div class="row">
    <label class="col-sm-2">Status</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <p-dropdown [options]="lkDiscrepancies" formControlName="statusObj" optionLabel="descr" placeholder=" Select ">
        </p-dropdown>
    </div>
    <label class="col-sm-2" *ngIf="loggedInUser.isAdmin">Assigned To</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4" *ngIf="loggedInUser.isAdmin">
        <p-dropdown [options]="usersList" formControlName="assignedTo" optionLabel="name" placeholder=" Select ">
        </p-dropdown>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is within  left panel and there is one  on the right too.
The left panel has the above code. My assigned To label moves to the next line like attached. How can I make them align on the same row.

[image]

Comment: Text inside label wraps because it doesn't have enough space to fit. Either widen your label or use `.text-nowrap` utility class

Comment: Make it `col-sm-3`

Comment: @Vona i cannot make it as col-sm-3 because the complete page is within col-sm-12.

Answer (score 0):

This is one solution:

```
<div class="row">
        <label class="col-sm-2">Status</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <p-dropdown [options]="lkDiscrepancies" formControlName="statusObj" optionLabel="descr" placeholder=" Select ">
            </p-dropdown>
        </div>
        <label class="col-sm-3" *ngIf="loggedInUser.isAdmin">Assigned To</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3" *ngIf="loggedInUser.isAdmin">
            <p-dropdown [options]="usersList" formControlName="assignedTo" optionLabel="name" placeholder=" Select ">
            </p-dropdown>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Downside is it will make the second drop down a different width than the first.

A second option would be to decrease the size of the text so it will not need the full 3 columns width before breaking to the next line.

In some cases you can also add css to the text so it won't break using nowrap however I wouldn't suggest that because it would probably end up overlapping the dropdown at some sizes.